# How can you show socket descriptions in My VIEW_3D panel into Blender 4.0?

Tags: python, node-editor

From some version I noticed that the node_groups sockets have a new "description" attribute which however was not visible in the interface until the Blender 4.0 version which now makes it possible to insert the description directly from the "Group" panel of the Shader Editor.

The description works well only if you hover over the Group node input, but not if you hover over the property drawn in the panel (See code example below)

I wonder if this is expected behavior, or something can be done about it to show the description in my Panel too

```
class MYADDON_PT_MyPanel(Panel):

    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_idname = "MYADDON_PT_MyPanel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "My Addon"

    def draw(self, context):
        
        ob = context.object
        if not ob:
            return
        mat = ob.active_material
        if not mat:
            return

        if not mat.use_nodes:
            return

        node_tree = mat.node_tree
        nodes = node_tree.nodes

        my_node = nodes.get("My Node")
        if not my_node:
            return


        layout = self.layout
        for n_input in my_node.inputs:
            layout.prop(n_input, 'default_value', text=n_input.name)
```

**Example**

[image]

Comment: Blender 4 has only just had its first beta release and isn't due for general release until  November so questions about it are off-topic here.   If you suspect it may be a bug you should report it via Blender's Help > Report a Bug menu giving a full description of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JohnEason can you point to a source stating it is off-topic? I don't see anything about βeta [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), in fact I don't see anything about αlpha… I could understand the reasoning of frowning upon alpha related questions/answers, because if the software changes (OK, it keeps changing, but old versions are available, and acquiring a particular alpha version is very hard) the content becomes obsolete. However this is not the case with beta versions - as long as a particular behavior is not a bug.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Apologies. I should have said that since it appears to be a bug in an unreleased version it is important to report it as a bug so that it can be corrected before the general release. I'm sure that I saw mention of reports on unreleased versions being off-topic a hile ago, but it looks asif I was wrong.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I don't know if there is a written rule but the matter of the fact is that most problems that users face with using alpha or beta versions will either be ironed out in the bug fixing phase, and/or should be reported to the bug tracker. Depending on the proximity of the official release date, things may or may not change without a warning so a valid answer may not be valid a few days later, and a question may not be valid a few days later.

Comment: That being said I think questions about Beta versions have their place here but only after the bug fixing phase has begun, and the API has stabilised and core features won't change drastically.